# Why I closed this 'resource' question

Tags: discusión, off-topic

#### [Download Spanish–English translations (esp. conjugations) as Open Data](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8360/12)

I recently closed the above question.  The OP, quite politely (thank you!) challenged my closure.  My explanation quickly outgrew a comment, so I will use this space to address the OP's points:

> I think it was a bit over-eager to use a mod vote to close this question and then engage debate.

It was a calculated move. :)

I honestly debated whether to close it, whether to simply comment, or whether to do nothing. And I chose the course which I thought was the most likely to solicit (healthy, hopefully!) debate on the issue.

> The question is clear and has verifiable answers, it is not a duplicate, it is not unclear, it is not too broad and it is not opinion-based.

I grant you each of those points. It is not a "bad subjective" question. It could, in theory, be somewhat open ended, as there could, again--theoretically--be multiple correct answers. Although I suspect the list of correct answers is quite small, and not likely to expand by much even over the coming years.

> Also I think it would be of interest to others.

Possibly. Although I suspect it's not likely to be of great interest to many people studying the Spanish language. It's really more of a computer science question, than a Language question.

> Nothing in the public [on-topic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) discussion suggests it as unsuitable.

That's true--it's not spelled out as explicitly off-topic, but it's also not spelled out as explicitly *on-topic* either.  And one of our close reasons is for "learning resources" which *are* off topic (and ought to be added to the help center text!)

I felt that, categorically, this question was closest to "learning resource" than to any other category of on- or off-topic question we have enumerated.  This is ultimately why I closed it--I felt it was in the spirit of our on/off-topic reasons, although admittedly it isn't within the letter of them

> @Flimzy, since you seemingly admit that closing might be debatable, would it not be more reasonable to allow it to be voted closed rather than using a unilateral mod vote? Anyways, my 2c. :)

Again, it was a calculated move, in an effort to get the community engaged.

These are my thoughts. What say the community?

There's no rule that resource questions must remain off-topic, if the community wants to make them on-topic again.

Comment: Tu sabes esa pregunta estaria buena para una wiki, pq como quiera es una informacion interesante,Tratar de hacer preguntas genericas q sirvan como referencia y marcarlas como comunity wiki asi como esta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: @EmilioGort no, el ejemplo que tú enlazas es distinto. PHP es finitio, tiene unos operadores finitos conocidos que no cambian. La pregunta cerrada, sin embargo, es como esta otra: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books Muy interesante, community wiki... pero fuera de lo que una pregunta de SE debe ser y por eso de cerró. Todo lo que sean "listas" que puedan crecer indefinidamente y que no puede haber una pregunta correcta sino varias, nunca podrán ser buenas preguntas aquí.